# Template Class in a scope defined by a function

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17

I have been working on finding a solution to this problem but have not been able to.

I would like a class with a **unknown** type be stored in **global scope**, this class will be defined by a function. Other functions will need to use this class like normal.

### Example

---

```cpp
// classes
class foo {
     public:

     foo(const char* str) {};
     void do_something() {};
};

class bar {
     public:

     bar(const char* str) {};
     void do_something() {};
};


// global obj (the part I need help with)
template <class T>
T globalObj;

// functions
template <class T>
void init(T obj) {
     globalObj = obj;
}

void use_obj() {
     globalObj.do_something();
}

// main
int main() {
     init(foo("some string"));
     
     use_obj();
     use_obj();
}
```

### Use Case

---

In the real application this would be used to set a video mode for a std output like `kprint()`. `kprint()` needs to know how to display to the screen, and the screen drivers are defined in a class, but I can't define a new class everywhere I use `kprint()`.

### Better case?

---

Is there a better way of doing this? I might be looking in the wrong direction with this solution.

If anyone wants I can provide a lot more detail.

#### I also don't have access to the std namespace, everything has to be done by scratch.

Comment: Isn’t this one of the standard motivations for virtual functions?  Make the global variable a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and then set it to an instance of whatever derived type in `init`?

Comment: @DavisHerring I don't work in the std namespace, I forgot to add that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That doesn’t change much: write your own `new` and `delete` in a destructor.

Comment: I second @DavisHerring : `globalObj` clearly wants to be a (possibly smart) pointer to a base class with virtual member function `do_something()`, that derived classes `foo` and `bar` override. `template <class T>T globalObj;` doesn't do what you appear to think it does - it doesn't define a single variable that can magically morph at run time to have any type, it defines an infinite family of variables, one for each possible type (of course only those that are actually used are instantiated).